# Modify XOR Neural network to other type of Neural networks

Tags: php, html, machine-learning, neural-network

I downloaded a neural network program written in PHP. It is for the XOR gate. I want to modify it into a program working for other data sets. Is it possible by just changing the training data set.

I changed this part. I used the data set ( 1,2, 1)- (3), (1,4,1)- (5), (2,2,1)-(4), (2,4,1)-6 instead of the training data set for the XOR gate.

The code is previously working but by just changing the training data set, it didn't work for me. Output generated was 1 for every data set. Would you please help me ?

```
        <?php
require_once ("class_neuralnetwork.php");

// Create a new neural network with 3 input neurons,
// 4 hidden neurons, and 1 output neuron
$n = new NeuralNetwork(3, 4, 1);
$n->setVerbose(false);

// Add test-data to the network. In this case,
// we want the network to learn the 'XOR'-function
$n->addTestData(array (-1, -1, 1), array (-1));
$n->addTestData(array (-1,  1, 1), array ( 1));
$n->addTestData(array ( 1, -1, 1), array ( 1));
$n->addTestData(array ( 1,  1, 1), array (-1));

// we try training the network for at most $max times
$max = 3;

echo "<h1>Learning the XOR function</h1>";
// train the network in max 1000 epochs, with a max squared error of 0.01
while (!($success = $n->train(1000, 0.01)) && ++$i<$max) {
    echo "Round $i: No success...<br />";
}

// print a message if the network was succesfully trained
if ($success) {
    $epochs = $n->getEpoch();
    echo "Success in $epochs training rounds!<br />";
}

echo "<h2>Result</h2>";
echo "<div class='result'>";
// in any case, we print the output of the neural network
for ($i = 0; $i < count($n->trainInputs); $i ++) {
    $output = $n->calculate($n->trainInputs[$i]);
    echo "<div>Testset $i; ";
    echo "expected output = (".implode(", ", $n->trainOutput[$i]).") ";
    echo "output from neural network = (".implode(", ", $output).")\n</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
//echo "<h2>Internal network state</h2>";
//$n->showWeights($force=true);

// Now, play around with some of the network's parameters a bit, to see how it 
// influences the result
$learningRates = array(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
$momentum = array(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1);
$rounds = array(100, 500, 1000, 2000);
$errors = array(0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.001);

echo "<h1>Playing around...</h1>";
echo "<p>The following is to show how changing the momentum & learning rate, 
in combination with the number of rounds and the maximum allowable error, can 
lead to wildly differing results. To obtain the best results for your 
situation, play around with these numbers until you find the one that works
best for you.</p>";
echo "<p>The values displayed here are chosen randomly, so you can reload 
the page to see another set of values...</p>";

for ($j=0; $j<10; $j++) {
    // no time-outs
    set_time_limit(0);

    $lr = $learningRates[array_rand($learningRates)];
    $m = $momentum[array_rand($momentum)];
    $r = $rounds[array_rand($rounds)];
    $e = $errors[array_rand($errors)];
    echo "<h2>Learning rate $lr, momentum $m @ ($r rounds, max sq. error $e)</h2>";
    $n->clear();
    $n->setLearningRate($lr);
    $n->setMomentum($m);
    $i = 0;
    while (!($success = $n->train($r, $e)) && ++$i<$max) {
        echo "Round $i: No success...<br />";
        flush();
    }

    // print a message if the network was succesfully trained
    if ($success) {
        $epochs = $n->getEpoch();
        echo "Success in $epochs training rounds!<br />";

        echo "<div class='result'>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($n->trainInputs); $i ++) {
            $output = $n->calculate($n->trainInputs[$i]);
            echo "<div>Testset $i; ";
            echo "expected output = (".implode(", ", $n->trainOutput[$i]).") ";
            echo "output from neural network = (".implode(", ", $output).")\n</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just in case you were wondering where the code is https://github.com/infostreams/neural-network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to give a definitive answer without seeing the code for the neural network implementation. But it looks like the implementation is probably using a `tanh` activation function, which would constrain neuron outputs to the range (-1, 1). Also, it appears that the implementation does not use an implicit bias input, which is why the example for the XOR function uses a third input that is explicitly set to 1 for all cases.

So the basic problem is that all of your target outputs are outside the range of the activation function. You need to restructure your network but how you do that will depend on what you are trying to accomplish. From your question, it isn't clear whether you are trying to train a classifier or interpolate a function.

If your four different outputs (3, 5, 4, and 6) represent classes, then you should define a network with four outputs and define the desired output values as follows:

```
$n = new NeuralNetwork(3, 4, 4);

$n->addTestData(array (1, 2, 1), array ( 1, -1, -1, -1));
$n->addTestData(array (1, 4, 1), array (-1,  1, -1, -1));
$n->addTestData(array (2, 2, 1), array (-1, -1,  1, -1));
$n->addTestData(array (2, 4, 1), array (-1, -1, -1,  1));
```

Note that you may want more than 4 hidden nodes for your example.

If you are attempting to do function interpolation, then you would keep just the single output neuron but need to scale your target output values to be in the range of the `tanh` function.